# How to make text clickable in TextSwitcher so that it can open another activity?

Tags: android, textview, context-switching, switchers

I have a Text Switcher in my app. Everything is working. My text is switching, but I want to open another activity when the text in the Text Switcher is clicked. How can I achieve this in android ??

Thanks in advance :)

Code of text switcher is ...

```
public class Course1 extends Activity
{
    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;
    Button btnNext;

    // Array of String to Show In TextSwitcher
    String textToShow[]={"Main HeadLine","Your Message","New In Technology","New Articles","Business News","What IS New"};
    int messageCount=textToShow.length;
    // to keep current Index of text
    int currentIndex=-1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              setContentView(R.layout.course1);                       

                // get The references
                btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
                mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);

                // Set the ViewFactory of the TextSwitcher that will create TextView object when asked
                mSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

                    public View makeView() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // create new textView and set the properties like clolr, size etc
                        TextView myText = new TextView(Course1.this);
                        myText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        myText.setTextSize(36);
                        myText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        return myText;
                    }
                });

                // Declare the in and out animations and initialize them 
                Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
                Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

                // set the animation type of textSwitcher
                mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
                mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);




                // ClickListener for NEXT button
                // When clicked on Button TextSwitcher will switch between texts
                // The current Text will go OUT and next text will come in with specified animation
                btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        currentIndex++;
                        // If index reaches maximum reset it
                        if(currentIndex==messageCount)
                            currentIndex=0;
                        mSwitcher.setText(textToShow[currentIndex]);
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(currentIndex==0){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        } else if(currentIndex==1){
                         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
                         startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: i want to open activity according to text ...i don't want to open same activity for every text i think it will open same activity for every text ?

Comment: then get the text in onClick method and open the specific activity you want

Comment: hey could you please vote up my answer please so other user can find  both the answer workable .

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the help of shylendra :) thanxx :)

here is my final code ....

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentIndex++;
        // If index reaches maximum reset it
        if(currentIndex==messageCount)
            currentIndex=0;
        mSwitcher.setText(textToShow[currentIndex]);
    }
});


mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(currentIndex==0)
        {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),lastyear.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else if(currentIndex==1)
    {
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);

    }

    }
});
```